# VB script error path Path not found(800A004C)

Tags: vbscript

I need to create vbscript which will create new folder 'test' and subfolder 'Output'.There is already a folder structure C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\Fmwire,I need to create test\Output under those structure

### I have created vbscript like this but i am getting error like this

Error:  Path not found
Code:   800A004C
Source:     Microsoft VBScript runtime error

```
Const OSCPATH = "\Fmwire\test\Output"
Const ALL_USERS_APPLICATION_DATA = &H23&

Dim fso                 ' File System Object
Dim objApplication      ' Application object
Dim objFolder           ' Folder object
Dim objFolderItem       ' FolderItem object
Dim fname               ' Path to Settings folder 






                Set objApplication  = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
                Set objFolder = objApplication.Namespace(ALL_USERS_APPLICATION_DATA)
                Set objFolderItem = objFolder.Self
                fname = objFolderItem.Path & OSCPATH

                Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
                If fso.FolderExists(fname) Then
                Set objFolder = fso.GetFolder(fname)
                Else
                Set objFolder = fso.CreateFolder(fname)
                   If Err Then
                     Err.Clear
                      strErr = SPOFOLDERFAIL
                      rCode = 4
                   End If
                End If
```

What changes i have to do for correcting this

Comment: It might be an ACL issue. Anyone can create Artifacts created under All users application data profile, but they will be not be writeable by any other user unless that user (or an admin) specifically removes the access restrictions so that anyone can modify items. Check existing permissions on that target folder.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Const OSCPATH = "\Fmwire\test\Output"
Const ALL_USERS_APPLICATION_DATA = &H23&

Set objApplication  = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objFolder = objApplication.Namespace(ALL_USERS_APPLICATION_DATA)
Set objFolderItem = objFolder.Self
fname = objFolderItem.Path

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
folders = Split(OSCPATH, "\")
For i = 0 To UBound(folders)
    fname = fso.BuildPath(fname, folders(i))
    If fso.FolderExists(fname) Then
        Set objFolder = fso.GetFolder(fname)
    Else
        Set objFolder = fso.CreateFolder(fname)
       If Err Then
         Err.Clear
          strErr = SPOFOLDERFAIL
          rCode = 4
       End If
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Thanks its working ,,what was the issue,,i am new to vbscript

Comment: You need to explicitly create each folder level that doesn't already exist (i.e., test, then test\Output).