# Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a004c' Path Not Found

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I am receiving this error after login: `Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a004c'  Path not found  /ppi/files.asp, line 23`.

How do I fix error?  See below:

```
  SQL = "SELECT * FROM [rapid_prod].[dbo].[PPI] WHERE [UserName] ='" & Request.Form("txtUserName") & "'"
  rs.Open SQL, Conn

If NOT rs.EOF Then
  If (Request.Form("txtUserPass")) = rs("Passwd") Then
   Session("TopUrl") = rs("PPI_Dir")
    Dim propertyname, propertydir
    propertyname = rs("Property_Name")
    propertydir = rs("PPI_Dir")
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    Conn.Close
    Set Conn = Nothing
    Response.Redirect "/ppi/files.asp?property="& propertyname &"&fold="&     propertydir
  End If
End If
```

In relation to the above code, I am adding the file for the redirect.  Here is the file.asp code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%
If Request.QueryString("fold")= "" then 
  'pthFolder="/ppi/"
  Response.Write("<center><br><br><br>There was either an error with your request<br> Or Your session timed out.<br><br><a href='../ppi.asp'>Return to the login page.</a></center>")
Else
  'pthFolder=pthFolder&"/ppi/"&Request.QueryString("fold")
  'pthFolder="/ppi/"&Request.QueryString("fold")
  sTopUrl = "files.asp?fold="&Session("TopUrl")
  pthFolder= Request.QueryString("fold")

  Set fso=Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

  'get all required info
  sParentFolder=fso.GetParentFolderName(pthFolder)
  If sParentFolder="" then sParentFolder="/"
  If left(sParentFolder,1)="/" or left(sParentFolder,1)="\" then sParentFolder=Mid(sParentFolder,2)
  sBackURL="files.asp?fold="&sParentFolder
  dim FolderSize
  FolderSize=0

  Set Folder=fso.GetFolder(Server.MapPath(pthFolder))


  'correct the pthFolder variable if it starts with a slash
  'we will not be using the mappath method anymore, so we can discard the slash
  If left(pthFolder,1)="/" or left(pthFolder,1)="\" then pthFolder=Mid(pthFolder,2)
  'now, if the folder name does not end with a slash, then add a slash
  If len(pthFolder)>0 and right(pthFolder,1)<>"/" and right(pthFolder,1)<>"\" then _
  pthFolder=pthFolder&"/"

%>
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<title>PPI</title>
<link href="ppi.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./fancybox/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.2.pack.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.1.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.1.css" media="screen" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {

            $("a#example5").fancybox({
                'titlePosition' : 'inside'
            });


        });
    </script>
<script>
function newWindow(urlname)

{
var a=window.open(urlname,'winName',"top=100, left=100, width=680, height=520, scrollbars=no");
a.focus();

}
</script>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<table width="760" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td valign="top" style="padding-bottom:20px;"><img src="img/banner.gif" width="760" height="133"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td valign="top">
    <br><br>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <table width="760" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
      <tr>
        <td width="568"><span class="body1">Viewing for: <b><a href="<% =sTopURL %>&property=<% = Request.QueryString("property") %>">
          <% = Request.QueryString("property") %>
        </a> /
        <% If Request.Querystring ("subprop") <> "" then %>
        <% If Request.Querystring ("level") = "eof" then %>
        <a href="<% =sBackURL %>&property=<% = Request.QueryString("property") %>&subprop=<% = Request.QueryString("subprop") %>">
        <% = Request.QueryString("subprop") %>
        </a>
        <% Else %>
        <% = Request.QueryString("subprop") %>
        <% End If %>
        <% End If %>
        </b></span>     </td>
        <td width="82" align="right"><a href="../ppi.asp?logout=true">Logout</a></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <br>

<% If Request.Querystring ("level") = "eof" then %> 

   <br>
   <table width="720" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
      <td width="347" class="body1">Vehicles for <b><% = Request.QueryString("month") %></b></td>
      <td width="168" align="right">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2"><span class="smallprint">Click on thumbnail for larger view</span> <br>
        <hr>      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>


<%
' ---------------- START FILE VIEW -------------------------------
Dim ImagePath
ImagePath = Request.QueryString("fold")
Response.write "<table width=""680"" align=""center"" border=""0"">"
'iColumnSpan is used as a column counter
iColumnSpan=0
response.write "<tr>"
'If there are records then loop through the fields  AND iColumnSpan <= IntPageSize
for each item in Folder.files

If iColumnSpan=4 Then
response.write "</tr><tr>"
iColumnSpan=0
End If

response.write "<td valign='top'>"
%>
      <a id="example5" href="<%=ImagePath%>/<%=item.Name%>" title="<%=item.Name%>"><img src="<%=ImagePath%>/<%=item.Name%>" alt="Click To Enlarge" border="0" height="113" width="150" class="img"></a>

      <!--<a href="javascript:newWindow('<%=ImagePath%>/<%=item.Name%>')"> <img src="<%=ImagePath%>/<%=item.Name%>" alt="Click To Enlarge" border="0" height="113" width="150" class="img"></a>--><br>
      <span class="smallprint" style="padding-left:11px; display:block;"><%=item.Name%></span>
      <br><br><br>
<%
response.write "</td>"

iColumnSpan=iColumnSpan + 1
next
response.write "</tr>"
Response.write "</table><br>"
' ---------------- END IMAGE VIEW -------------------------------
%>
<center><br><br></center>
<% 
Else
' ---------------- START FOLDER VIEW ------------------------------- %>
<br>
<table width="680" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="247"><em>Folder</em></td>
    <td width="303"><em>Last Modified</em></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2"><hr size=1></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table width="680"  border="0" align="center" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="5" class="body1">
  <tr valign="top">
<%
for each item in Folder.SubFolders
If right(item.Name,2) > "12" then 
 DirLabel = item.Name
 SubProperty = item.Name
Else
FolderView = "eof"
SubProperty = Request.QueryString("subprop")
If right(item.Name,2) = "01" then DirLabel = "January " & left(item.Name,2) End If
If right(item.Name,2) = "02" then DirLabel = "February " & left(item.Name,2) End If
If right(item.Name,2) = "03" then DirLabel = "March " & left(item.Name,2) End If
If right(item.Name,2) = "04" then DirLabel = "April " & left(item.Name,2) End If
If right(item.Name,2) = "05" then DirLabel = "May " & left(item.Name,2) End If
If right(item.Name,2) = "06" then DirLabel = "June " & left(item.Name,2) End If
If right(item.Name,2) = "07" then DirLabel = "July " & left(item.Name,2) End If
If right(item.Name,2) = "08" then DirLabel = "August " & left(item.Name,2) End If
If right(item.Name,2) = "09" then DirLabel = "September " & left(item.Name,2) End If
If right(item.Name,2) = "10" then DirLabel = "October " & left(item.Name,2) End If
If right(item.Name,2) = "11" then DirLabel = "November " & left(item.Name,2) End If
If right(item.Name,2) = "12" then DirLabel = "December " & left(item.Name,2) End If
End If
%>
    <td width="20" align="center"><img src="img/folder.gif" width="16" height="13"></td>
    <td width="211"><a href="files.asp?month=<%=DirLabel%>&level=<%=FolderView%>&property=<% = Request.QueryString("property") %>&subprop=<%=SubProperty%>&fold=<%=pthFolder%><%=item.Name%>"><%=DirLabel%></a></td>
    <td width="308"><span class="smallprint"><%=item.DateLastModified%></span></td>
  </tr>
<% Next %>
</table>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<%' ---------------- END FOLDER VIEW -------------------------------%>
<% End If %>

  <br>  </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="center" valign="top"><br>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br>

<%
function fit(text,length)
    'function to make text fit a given length, so that it does not overflow the cell width.
    If len(text)>(length-3) then
        text=left(text,(length-3))
        text=text&"..."
        fit=text
    else
        fit=text
    end if
end function
%> 
</BODY>
</HTML>
<% End If %>
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add relevant code snippet (line 23 neighbourhood) satisfying  [mcve]. Using reversed slashes could help: `\ppi\files.asp`.

Comment: Not sure about backslashes here.  It would be relevant if you were using `Server.Mappath`.Try forward slashes in your redirect path, or try the full external url (ie `Response.Redirect "http://www.yoursite.com/path-to/ppi/files.asp?property= etc"`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VB script error path Path not found(800A004C)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5729903/vb-script-error-path-path-not-found800a004c)

Answer (score 0):

should the '**' be in your redirect url?
probably need more info really but the problem could be happening in the script that this one redirects to.

Comment: No, it should not be there.

Comment: can you paste your files.asp?